# Google App Engine storing large strings in datastore in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have some pdf files stored in the blobstore , i want to convert them to text and store them in datastore . The problem is the pdf files are very large , so there corresponding text may exceed the 1 MB limit of the datastore Text property. So can someone tell how to save these large text strings to datastore.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the reason for not storing them in the blobstore?

Comment: because writing files to blobstore has been deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past you would have used the blobstore but that has been deprecated and now you should use google cloud storage.  It has has a similiar api

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/

Comment: you are right but due to some project requirements i cant use the cloud storage, is there anyway to store large strings in datastore?

Comment: All you can do is break it up into parts across multiple entities/records.  A single entity is limited to 1MB.  Are your pdf's compressed ?

Comment: The gcs client lib has a file like api, and you can set your permissions on the bucket so that no could access the file directly, but would have to go through your app.  - In that case would it be any different to the outside world that the data isn't in the datastore?

Comment: Thanks for the "break it up into parts across multiple entities/records" advice.